Using Python ipaddress module to sort strings starting with an IP address
I'm looking at this older article that shows how to sort IP address strings using the numerical value instead of text.
The example given is this:
#!/usr/bin/python
import ipaddress

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
   ips = sorted(ipaddress.ip_address(line.strip()) for line in f)
   print('\n'.join(map(str, ips)))

In my case, the IP addresses are the first part of a list of strings iplist, and not read from a file of lines.
172.16.0.186     be:b6:5a:34:ee:3a
172.16.0.19      5c:cf:7f:59:f6:fd
172.16.0.212     48:a2:e6:b0:6d:3f
172.16.0.222     80:6a:10:3:d8:19 
172.16.0.223     34:85:18:5d:3f:78
172.16.0.229     34:19:4d:1c:53:a6
172.16.0.27      c0:4e:30:1e:5:70 
172.16.0.28      84:f3:eb:4e:38:b5
172.16.0.29      7c:9e:bd:bc:cf:44
172.16.0.30      9c:76:13:b7:39:97

I tried to modify the code above to iterate over iplist and slice off the start of the string that contains only the IP address:
ips = sorted(ipaddress.ip_address(line[:16].strip()) for line in iplist)

That gives the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ip_address'"
Looking at the docs for the ipaddress module, it appears that ipaddress.ip_address()  does take a string.
ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.1')
IPv4Address('192.168.0.1')


You have assigned a string variable to ipaddress.  You need to import ipaddress again to rebind this name back to a module, then your existing code should work. Voting to close as non-repo/typo.

Yep, that was it - ipaddress had already been used as a string variable. I just changed that variable to another name. Thanks!
